Using cloned GitHub repo in Vite project
I am new to JS development and have made a clone of a github repo and made local changes that I need to that clone. I now want to use the clone in my project, which is packaged with vite. How do I use the local clone with my changes as a dependency in my main project?
I have tried:

Adding the local path of my clone as a dependency in my package.json
Reuploading the fork to github and adding the github repo as a dependency in package.json.

Neither seems to work, I get the following error:
[vite] Pre-transform error: Failed to resolve import "roughjs/bin/rough" from "node_modules/excalidraw-gp/packages/excalidraw/renderer/renderElement.ts?v=38f63b61"
